# How to make floating label bold for TextInputLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-textinputlayout

I have a `TextInputLayout`. I try to apply custom `hintTextAppearance` style

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/wizard_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/wizard_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/wizard_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/wizard_vertical_margin">

    <TextView
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/wizard_vertical_margin"
        android:text="What's your email address?"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="?attr/wizardTextViewColor"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:id="@+id/text_view" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/WizardTextInputLayout"
        android:id="@+id/text_input_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:hint="Email address"
            android:id="@+id/email_edit_text" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I try to make the text bold by applying the following custom style.

```
<style name="WizardTextInputLayout" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

However, it looks no different before & after applying the custom style.

### Before custom `hintTextAppearance` style

[image]

### After custom `hintTextAppearance` style

[image]

I can confirm the styling works. As, if I add `android:textSize` attribute in `WizardTextInputLayout` style, I can see there is change on floating label text size.

But, why making the floating label text bold doesn't work? Anything I can try out to make the floating label text bold?

Comment: Hey, buddy were you able to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

### Update

As setting a custom typeface for the textinputLayout will affect the hint text appearance and style that is mananged by it, you can use the `setHintTextAppearance(int resId)` method of `TextInputLayout`, with providing a custom text style xml, to overcome the issue.

### Original Answer

You can create a custom class extending the `TextInputLayout` class and overriding the `setTypeFace()` method :

```
    @Override
public void setTypeface(@Nullable Typeface typeface) {
    setTypeface(Your_Bold_typeface);
}
```

where you should set a typeface created from the bold version of your desired font.

Comment: It will change the floating text bold. However, it will also introduce another unwanted side effect. It will change the font for hint text (The text when there is nothing in EditText) as well.

Comment: You can use the textinputlayout.setHintTextAppearance(int resId) to give a specific text style to hint that is managed by it.

Comment: setHintTextAppearance can only change text size, not bold.